# unable to run npm after installing nodejs in windows 10?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

i downloaded nodejs and installed with node package manager.
After installing when i typed..

```
node -v
```

i am getting response as

```
v.6.11.1
```

But when i type

```
npm -v
```

i am not gettin any response.then when i give ctrl+c to terminate i am getting response as

```
Terminate batch job(y/n)?
```

I have tried reinstalling several times but couldnt able to run npm installation.Any help?

Comment: Check if the binaries of npm are added to your PATH. An easier way to install node/npm on windows machines is by using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)

Comment: Actually the environment variable path is set as
'C:\Program Files\nodejs\ only' and not as 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\''

Comment: also i am unable to change the pah as C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Comment: But the latest node version is 7.4 , i think its not properly installed. And dont forget to give the path in env in windows .

Comment: Why are you unable to add the npm to PATH?

Comment: No idea ..@borgdanc

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps you will get the node and npm installation successful:

1. download Nodejs from the link https://nodejs.org/en/
2. download V6.11.1 LTS (long term support)
3. type `npm install -g @angular/cli` in the command promt
4. check the version now by typing `npm -v` in the command prompt and `node -v`

Answer (score 0):

I think node js is not installed properly in your system.

Try to reinstall it and then do this process again.

Answer (score 0):

It may not installed properly, Reinstall npm

Try this link https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/